# jQuery ajax success handler not modifying global object

Tags: jquery, scope

In my code below, I have a function that asynchronously loads all files necessary for an app and when all files are loaded I continue app execution:

```
function loadDATA(){
    var numFILES=6;
    var numLoaded=0;

    var dfd=$.Deferred();
    function fetchJSON(fileName,toObj){
        $.ajax({url: fileName, dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    if(data){
                        toObj=data;
                    }
                    numLoaded++;
                    if(numLoaded==numFILES){dfd.resolve()};
                }
        });
    }

    fetchJSON(TOCfile,TOC);
    fetchJSON(MAPfile,MAP);
    fetchJSON(CONTENTfile,CONTENT);
    fetchJSON(TABLESfile,TABLES);
    fetchJSON(CAPTIONSfile,CAPTIONS);
    fetchJSON(BOXESfile,BOXES);

    return dfd;
}
```

The objects `TOC, MAP, CONTENT, TABLES, CAPTIONS, BOXES` are all pre-defined globally to `{}` at the top of the script.

loaDATA is called like so:

```
loadDATA().done(function(){
    //do stuff with all loaded data here
})
```

Everything works as expected EXCEPT that the GLOBAL objects are not assigned the new value. INSIDE the `success` handler, `toObj` has the value of `data`, but the GLOBAL object is not modified. Why? Does it have to do with scope?

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying what `toObj` points to, not what the global points to when you say `toObj = data`.

For example, this should work:

```
toObj.data = data;
```

That's because you're adding a new attribute. Alternatively, you could something like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) { 
    toObj[key] = value;
});
```

Comment: "You're modifying what toObj points to".....That's what I want to do I want to modify the global object that toObj points to, and doesn't toObj 'point to' the corresponding global object? I've tried extending the object as well w/o success: `toObj=$.extend({},data)` inside of the success handler. sorry if I'm misunderstanding something...

Comment: And Javascript doesn't let you do it like that. JavaScript uses a form of pass by value and reference that's similar to Java. Each object variable is a reference to a memory address. However, unlike C or C++, you don't have syntax to say "change the value, not the memory address this thing points to."

Comment: thanks Mike.. Yes that's the equivalent of what I'm trying to do here. See my edit above..I've tried copying everything over using jQuery's extend() function but can't do it that way either.

Comment: toObj=$.extend({},data) still suffers from the same problem. Just try manually copying all of the properties over.

Comment: ok Mike, I tried your solution. It works fantastically. Thank you. ...and it turns out I was using $.extend() incorrectly. This works: `$.extend(toObj,data)`, while `toObj=$.extend({},data);` doesn't.